# Computing the density of states (DOS) using quantum espresso (QE) is not working, partially

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, density-of-states

[image]I am trying to compute the density of states of rutile and anatase (TiO2) using Quantum Espresso package. A very basic calculation. However, after all the procedures (scf + nscf + dos) the resulting density of states only shows data below the Fermi level and I cannot see any band gap as it should above 10 eV (check Figure). I have already included Hubbard U correction; the issue is present in MoS2 calculations as well. Does anyone has a clue or has faced a similar situation? Many thanks for considering my request.

After some experimentation, seems that I have better results when the number of bands in the nscf input file equals the total number of electrons (second figure)

```
nbnd = # of electrons
```

As per the supporting information from QE:

```
nbnd = # of electrons / 2
```

with a Fermi energy of ~9.05 eV.

[image]

SCF Input file for rutile

```
! restart_mode = 'restart'
! time wall of 2 h
! k-points distance of 0.2 A-1
! using atomic positions and cell parameters from structural optimization 
&CONTROL
  restart_mode = 'from_scratch'
  title = 'TiO2 rutile scf'
  calculation = 'scf'
  etot_conv_thr =   6.0000000000d-05
  forc_conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-04
  outdir = './tmp/'
  prefix = 'rutile-scfHU'
  pseudo_dir = '/home/ps_pbe_eff/'
  tprnfor = .true.
  tstress = .true.
  verbosity = 'high'
  max_seconds = 7.2d+3
/
&SYSTEM
  ecutrho =   5.0000000000d+02
  ecutwfc =   5.0000000000d+01
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 6
  nosym = .false.
  ntyp = 2
  occupations = 'fixed'
/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr =   1.2000000000d-09
  electron_maxstep = 80
  mixing_beta =   4.0000000000d-01
/
&IONS
/
&CELL
  press_conv_thr=0.1
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
O      15.9994 O.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.0.1.UPF
Ti     47.867 ti_pbe_v1.4.uspp.F.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Ti            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.0000000000
Ti            0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.5000000000
O             0.6948896839        0.6948896839        0.5000000000
O             0.1948896839        0.8051103161        0.0000000000
O             0.8051103161        0.1948896839        0.0000000000
O             0.3051103161        0.3051103161        0.5000000000 
K_POINTS automatic
10 10 15 0 0 0
CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
   4.642542635   0.000000000   0.000000000
   0.000000000   4.642542635   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000   2.963491358
HUBBARD {ortho-atomic}
U Ti-3d 5.7066
```

NSCF input file for

```
! restart_mode = 'restart'
! time wall of 2 h
! k-points distance of 0.2 A-1
! using atomic positions and cell parameters from structural optimization
&CONTROL
  restart_mode = 'from_scratch'
  title = 'TiO2 rutile nscf'
  calculation = 'nscf'
  etot_conv_thr =   6.0000000000d-05
  forc_conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-04
  outdir = './tmp/'
  prefix = 'rutile-scfHU'
  pseudo_dir = '/home/ps_pbe_eff/'
  tprnfor = .true.
  tstress = .true.
  verbosity = 'high'
  max_seconds = 7.2d+3
/
&SYSTEM
  ecutrho =   5.0000000000d+02
  ecutwfc =   5.0000000000d+01
  ibrav = 0
  nat = 6
  nbnd = 24
  nosym = .false.
  occupations = 'tetrahedra'
  ntyp = 2
  nbnd = 48
/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr =   1.2000000000d-09
  electron_maxstep = 80
  mixing_beta =   4.0000000000d-01
/
&IONS
/
&CELL
  press_conv_thr=0.1
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
O      15.9994 O.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.0.1.UPF
Ti     47.867 ti_pbe_v1.4.uspp.F.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
Ti            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.0000000000
Ti            0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.5000000000
O             0.6948896839        0.6948896839        0.5000000000
O             0.1948896839        0.8051103161        0.0000000000
O             0.8051103161        0.1948896839        0.0000000000
O             0.3051103161        0.3051103161        0.5000000000 
K_POINTS automatic
10 10 15 0 0 0
CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
   4.642542635   0.000000000   0.000000000
   0.000000000   4.642542635   0.000000000
   0.000000000   0.000000000   2.963491358
HUBBARD {ortho-atomic}
U Ti-3d 5.7066
```

And the out file for the DOS

````
     Program DOS v.7.1 starts on 23Aug2023 at  9:46:18 

     This program is part of the open-source Quantum ESPRESSO suite
     for quantum simulation of materials; please cite
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 21 395502 (2009);
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Phys.:Condens. Matter 29 465901 (2017);
         "P. Giannozzi et al., J. Chem. Phys. 152 154105 (2020);
          URL http://www.quantum-espresso.org", 
     in publications or presentations arising from this work. More details at
     http://www.quantum-espresso.org/quote

     Parallel version (MPI), running on     1 processors

     MPI processes distributed on     1 nodes
     252587 MiB available memory on the printing compute node when the environment starts
 

     Reading xml data from directory:

     ./tmp/rutile-scfHU.save/
     file O.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.0.1.UPF: wavefunction(s)  2P renormalized

     IMPORTANT: XC functional enforced from input :
     Exchange-correlation= PBE
                           (   1   4   3   4   0   0   0)
     Any further DFT definition will be discarded
     Please, verify this is what you really want

 
     G-vector sticks info
     --------------------
     sticks:   dense  smooth     PW     G-vecs:    dense   smooth      PW
     Sum        3061    1225    373                81347    20585    3401
 
     Using Slab Decomposition
 

     Check: negative core charge=   -0.000007

     negative rho (up, down):  3.142E-03 0.000E+00

     Tetrahedra used

 
     DOS          :   1m 8.93s CPU   1m10.19s WALL

 
   This run was terminated on:   9:47:28  23Aug2023            

=------------------------------------------------------------------------------=
   JOB DONE.
=------------------------------------------------------------------------------=
```
````

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! This post applies also to SharePoint though: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/5, so please provide your input file in a `code` block or on GitHub.

Comment: @OscarLopez You have only shared the input files. Could you share the output files too as a code block? Especially, the output of the `scf` calculation and the `dos.x` output, i.e., the data file you used to plot the graph.

Comment: What is the Fermi level for this calculation?

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I have added the out files to the link provided. Since the last time, I experimented with the variables, and seems that I need to use nbnd equal to the total number of electrons, and not the total number of electrons divided by two as indicated by the supporting information from QE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because you still have a link to Sharepoint and seem to have ignored my previous comment.

Comment: My bad, @NikeDattani, kind of new here.

Comment: The fact that you're new doesn't stop you from reading comments and following instructions though.